# How to Get CurrentUserId in WebApi2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

### Current User Id in WebApi2

I want to  get to current user-id, I tried following things

```
string currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId()

string currentUserId1 =
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

but it always returns null,
Another approach is :-

To implement extension method on IIdentity interface in Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IdentityExtensions. 
but don't know how to implement this method with interface IIdentity  as input parameter.

Event having content on internet and stack-overflow none of the example worked

Not able to understand why the above one liner code doesn't work.
Can any body give working example. Stuck here.

Comment: are you sure you're logged in when trying this?

Comment: I am using WebApi only, and testing my functionality via Fidller, From Login point of  view i am not logged in as Specific User, Working on remote machine so i have windows credentials only

Answer (score 0):

Where in your code are you using this?

Not only, but you should be able to, get this atleast inside a **Api** controller.

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;

---

[Authorize]//makes sure the user is authenticated 
//or use User.Identity.IsAuthenticated before getting the ID.
public class AccountController : ApiController
{
     public IHttpActionResult Get()
     {
          string userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
          return Ok();
     }
}
```

Comment: This code gives error as  All code path does not return value, also how IHttpActionResult  can return string ?

Comment: Well I expected that you have some knowledge of asp.net webapi, what you return is up to you,it is just an example. Anyway, edited the answer. Within `Ok()` you can return any data. But, within the scope of this question, userId should not be null if logged in. Don't forget the namespaces...

Comment: Thanks Cular, I am using standalone webapi, so log in means where should be logged in ? in any specific account ?

Comment: I'm sorry Navin, but that is outside the scope of this question. Logging in via an API can be googled quite easy, you use Bearer tokens, Oauth protocol. Good luck ;). Once you succeeded with that, come back to this question and accept the answer if it worked...